# How to avoid 'blank activity' flick during navigation

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation, xamarin.android, xamarin

I have Android app with custom headers for every activity view.
I'm using Activities without title:

```
RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
```

When I'm navigating from one `Activity` to another, what I see is first a blank `Activity` with title, then my desired `View` without title.

What should I do in order not to see that blank `Activity`?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me that a lot of stuff is going on in your `OnCreate`'s. Try to minimize that.

Additionally you can set a Theme for your `Activity` which looks more like what it is going to view. My opinion on using `RequestWindowFeature` to hide the title or `ActionBar` is that it should be avoided if possible and use a theme instead.

What I would do is to create a `Resources/Values/style.xml` file like this:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="MyTheme.Default" parent="@android:style/Theme"></style>
    <style name="MyTheme.NoTitle" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"></style>
</resources>
```

To support API 11 create a `Resources/Values-v11/style.xml` with:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="MyTheme.Default" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo"></style>
    <style name="MyTheme.NoTitle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar"></style>
</resources>
```

And again for API 14 a `Resources/Values-v14/style.xml` with:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="MyTheme.Default" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"></style>
    <style name="MyTheme.NoTitle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"></style>
</resources>
```

Then in all your Activities use the `Theme` property in the `Activity` flag like so:

```
[Activity(Label="My Activity", Theme="@style/MyTheme.NoTitle")]
public class MyActivity : Activity
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: It makes sense. I will try it asap and let you know if it helps.

Comment: Can you not achieve what your app requires by using Fragments instead of multiple Activities?